# Learning representation for growth curves to create new growth curves

Tags: statistics

I have growth curve data which generally has this shape to them:
[example of growth curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKG1F.png)

For an experiment I would like "fake" curves based on my sample data(n~15) and I need to create realistic looking curves to survey people with.

Are there any specific methods that are well suited for this?

I have tried googling it but unrelated results keep showing up.